# MySQL - Sum the result and join in single query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

The total sum of hours for respective program from table 1 should multiply with prod_count on table 2.

For example : Lets take a user - ram

ram has worked on two programs `pro-1 = 9hr (5 + 4)` and `pro-2 = 6 hr`  *[from table 1]*

prod_count for `pro-1 is 200` and `pro-2 is 120` *[from table 2]*

so ideally it should be `200*9 = 1800` and `120*6 = 720`

so `total is (1800 + 720) = 2520`

`total task count is (656 + 23 + 44) = 723` *[from table 1]*

Result for ram should be `ram, 2520 , 723`

Table 1

```
| id | name  | program | task_hours | task_count |
|----|-------|---------|------------|------------|
| 1  | raj   | pro-1   | 6.5        | 344        |
| 2  | raj   | pro-2   | 2          | 324        |
| 3  | ram   | pro-1   | 5          | 656        |
| 4  | ram   | pro-1   | 4          | 23         |
| 5  | ram   | pro-2   | 6          | 44         |
| 6  | kumar | pro-2   | 7          | 345        |
| 7  | kumar | pro-3   | 4          | 222        |
```

Table 2

```
| id | program | prod_count |
|----|---------|------------|
| 1  | pro-1   | 200        |
| 2  | pro-2   | 120        |
| 3  | pro-3   | 60         |
```

Expected result :

```
 name  | total_calc | total_count |
|-------|------------|-------------|
| raj   | 1540       | 668         |
| ram   | 2520       | 723         |
| kumar | 1080       | 567         |
```

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f75e15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables and aggregate:

```
select t1.name,
       sum(t1.task_hours * t2.prod_count) total_calc,
       sum(t1.task_count) total_count
from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2
on t2.program = t1.program
group by t1.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hpHLK3v2Qm5qZYqvvY6eoh/1).
Results:

```
| name  | total_calc | total_count |
| ----- | ---------- | ----------- |
| kumar | 1080       | 567         |
| raj   | 1540       | 668         |
| ram   | 2520       | 723         |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb5f61/1/0

```
select
  name,
  sum(task_hours * prod_count) total_calc,
  sum(task_count) total_count
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.program = t2.program
group by name
order by t1.id
```

Noted: task_hours should be float type.